# How can I further simplify this piece of LINQ code

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code that I use to bind to a repeater:

```
Repeater rpt;

var q = from t in new[] { 10 }
        select new { ID = t };

rpt.DataSource = q;
rpt.DataBind();
```

Is there a simpler way to accomplish this code segment; the `var q` part?

Comment: +1. It didn't even occur to me to solve initialization this way.  Thanks for the idea :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Repeater rpt;

rpt.DataSource = new[] { new { ID = 10 } };
rpt.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You could write it like this if you prefer:

```
var q = new[] { 10 }.Select(t => new { ID = t });
rpt.DataSource = q;
rpt.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't get much simpler than that.

You could inline the variable, so that it becomes:

```
Repeater rpt = ...;

rpt.DataSource = from t in new[] { 10 }
                 select new { ID = t };
rpt.DataBind();
```